# How to obtain entire data state of MUI Data Grid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

How do you access the state object of a MUI Datagrid data? I.e. the original data you populated it, plus any edits that have occurred.

It must be accessible because you can export the data as .csv. I would instead like to obtain it as JSON and post to my server.

E.g.

```
<DataGridPro rows={rows} columns={columns} />
```

*User now edits multiple cells*

```
let updatedRows = ???
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different event callbacks you can rely on you can take a look into the documentation at: https://mui.com/api/data-grid/data-grid-pro/ just do a search for anything starting wit `on` e.g `onCellClick` but since you mentioned state I picked `onStateChange` for example below

```js
<DataGridPro 
  rows={rows} 
  columns={columns}
  onStateChange={(state) => setUpdatedState(state)} 
/>

// there's also a rows specific callback
<DataGridPro 
  rows={rows} 
  columns={columns}
  onEditRowsModelChange={(state) => setUpdatedRowsState(state)} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks - but the state here is only the single cell/row that has been modified. I'm after a way to obtain the state of the entire data grid without having to track and update after each individual event. E.g. what the export as .csv offers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [state selector](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/state/#catalog-of-selectors)
For example, the gridSortedRowEntriesSelector will provide you sorted rows.

About how to use selectors, it will depends on where you need to access this data

Comment: By the way, there is a demo showing how to add a JSON export button. Maybe it can help you

https://mui.com/components/data-grid/export/#custom-export-format